# Loss Calculations for LSTM + TimeDistributed(Dense...) layers

Tags: keras

I have a simple sequential model using TimeDistributed(Dense...) as the final layer after an LSTM layer. I am training on time series data in sequences of 20 time steps. The loss function is Mean Absolute Error, defined as:

```
def mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred):
  return K.mean(K.abs(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

(from https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py)

A snippet of the model is:

```
LSTM(
    framelen
    , return_sequences=True
)
TimeDistributed(
    Dense(
        framelen
        , activation="relu"
    )
)
```

The data being fed is of size (batches, timesteps, framelen), where timesteps is 20 as stated, batches covers the whole dataset, and framelen is 13 parameters scaled to 0 - 1.0. The final result should be a set of framelen parameters predicting the next steps in the sequence.

I am trying to confirm whether the standard loss functions do actually calculate loss across all the time steps in the output. Looking at the code it looks like the loss may just be calculated on a single time step, but that could be just my poor understanding of the code.

I have attempted to run the same training with both this model and the equivalent where the final layer is a plain Dense (and obviously structuring the expected output as a single step each time). The plain Dense model appears to train far better than the TimeDistributed equivalent. The former manages to converge at a lower minimum and the qualitative output is much better.

Does anybody have good insight into the way the loss functions work when time series data is used with TimeDistributed as the output? Does it achieve a calculation of loss for each time step in the output? And if so, how does it use a loss that is a scalar value?

Answer (score 4):

The way they work depends entirely on how they're defined.

Most usually, all elements in the tensor do participate in the loss function. 
What may change is the order in which they're processed, if they're summed before or after some calculation. They're grouped by axes (dimensions equal to your target data). So, the order of the calculations (which axis is considered first), and the order in which they're summed and in which the mean results are taken.

In Keras, the most usual is to see that it calculates sublosses in the last axis of the tensors, and then it makes the mean or sum.

When you're working with a time series output in the form `(samples, steps, featuresOrClasses)`, Keras' standard functions will often work grouping by `featuresOrClasses`, and then the sum and mean values are calculated.

This is logical for classification problems, for instance. If you have 3 output classes and you want a `categorical_crossentropy`, this result must be calculated individually in each time step, considering only 3 classes. So it's fine to calculate results in the last axis (which is the only axis that considers 3 classes) and then summing for the steps and samples.

But it's not enough to tell you why your losses were different. This depends on what your targets are. Are they classes? Are they foretelling a series? Etc.

The main difference is that there will be way more elements participating in the loss. It's probably harder indeed to fit all of them.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth response. Based on your answer to the custom loss question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47432758/483133 and your response here, it would seem to me that the standard Keras mean absolute loss definition (I'll edit my question to include this code) would not work well where a final LSTM is doing `return_sequences=True` (then passed through a TimeDistributed Dense layer), since the only loss would be calculated on the final result in the time series. To get the desired equivalent effect of step by step loss measurement I'd need to update axis=1 on the loss function

Comment: It will consider all the steps. But grouped by the last axis. This means that all steps will be seen as different samples. (But having lots of steps multiplies the number of samples).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Here is what I think I grasp from your comment. An input of 20 steps of 13 parameters passed into the LSTM with return_sequences=True will return 20 steps x 13 parameters as a prediction. The loss will only look at the last step of these (result[19], having 13 elements), then apply that same loss across the remaining steps [0:19] too, without calculating their own losses? If so, that is not what I want!

Comment: No, it will calculate a loss for each of the steps, grouping 13 parameters in each of these step losses. Then it will sum and mean all these step losses.

Comment: Although there is an `axis=-1`, which applies to the `mean` function, the calculations are done using all the values in the tensor. Keras will later at some point also make a mean considering the axes that remained.

Comment: I think your final statement in your answer says it all "The main difference is that there will be way more elements participating in the loss. It's probably harder indeed to fit all of them.". I'm going to digest this for a while and mark your answer as accepted. I appreciate your detailed insights.

Comment: You could experiment some function in Lambda layers, creating models just with the functions you don't understand. Then you predict with these models and see what the functions are truly doing.

Comment: great idea - I'll give that a shot

Comment: I have a similar question about the loss. I have 4-dim sequences (really long ones) and I am trying to predict single value output. I am using `stateful` LSTM with 32 `timesteps` and a `TimeDistributed(Dense())` layer. If I try to use `mean-absolute_error` loss, does it take into account every step?

Comment: Yes, it takes every step into account.