# Writing a custom loss function element by element for Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am new to machine learning, python and tensorflow. I am used to code in C++ or C# and it is difficult for me to use tf.backend.
I am trying to write a custom loss function for an LSTM network that tries to predict if the next element of a time series will be positive or negative. My code runs nicely with the binary_crossentropy loss function. I want now to improve my network having a loss function that adds the value of the next time series element if the predicted probability is greater than 0.5 and substracts it if the prob is less or equal to 0.5.
I tried something like this:

```
def customLossFunction(y_true, y_pred):
    temp = 0.0
    for i in range(0, len(y_true)):
        if(y_pred[i] > 0):
            temp += y_true[i]
        else:
            temp -= y_true[i]
    return temp
```

Obviously, dimensions are wrong but since I cannot step into my function while debugging, it is very hard to get a grasp of dimensions here.
Can you please tell me if I can use an element-by-element function? If yes, how? And if not, could you help me with tf.backend?
Thanks a lot

Comment: did you get any errors from this? Could you edit your question and include them. I think you may need to consider how you can do this without the for loop, with a function that processes all elements of the the predicted data in a single operation.

Comment: Using info from https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/math_ops try something like from `keras import backend as K; def customLossFunction(y_true, y_pred): return K.mean(K.sign(y_pred) * y_true, axis=-1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From keras backend functions, you have the function `greater` that you can use:

```
import keras.backend as K

def customLossFunction(yTrue,yPred)

    greater = K.greater(yPred,0.5)
    greater = K.cast(greater,K.floatx()) #has zeros and ones
    multiply = (2*greater) - 1 #has -1 and 1

    modifiedTrue = multiply * yTrue

    #here, it's important to know which dimension you want to sum
    return K.sum(modifiedTrue, axis=?)
```

The `axis` parameter should be used according to what you want to sum.

```
axis=0 -> batch or sample dimension (number of sequences)     
axis=1 -> time steps dimension (if you're using return_sequences = True until the end)     
axis=2 -> predictions for each step
```

Now, if you have only a 2D target:

```
axis=0 -> batch or sample dimension (number of sequences)
axis=1 -> predictions for each sequence
```

If you simply want to sum everything for every sequence, then just don't put the axis parameter.

### Important note about this function:

Since it contains only values from `yTrue`, it cannot backpropagate to change the weights. This will lead to a "none values not supported" error or something very similar.

Although `yPred` (the one that is connected to the model's weights) is used in the function, it's used only for getting a true x false condition, which is not differentiable.

Comment: The axis information is useful. May I ask if there is a reference you got this from? I have had an issue in the past attempting to get losses to work with TimeDistributed / return_sequences=True results. You may want to answer my question here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765136/loss-calculations-for-lstm-timedistributeddense-layers

Comment: The shape of the tensors `yTrue` and `yPred` is the output shape of your `model.summary()`, which is also the shape of your targets. If you understand your data, you understand the axes. The description of the functions is [here](https://keras.io/backend/)

Comment: I agree that now you have stated it the way you did in your answer the axis parameter makes sense. The documentation doesn't state it as clearly in terms of LSTM sequences, and I hadn't made the mental leap to what you described.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I still have the error message "Tried to convert 'x' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.". Is it because of greater+cast being not differentiable?

Comment: Oh, surely! This function is not differentiable (regarding the weights), because it depends only on `yTrue` in the end. The function must depend on `yPred`. (There aren't `yPred` values in this function, only a condition that uses them, and the condition is not differentiable).